# Definition of orghogonal / orghonormal

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, terminology

We thought at first that it was a misprint but it really seems that "orghogonal" or "orghonormal" (with a g) means something different from "orthogonal" or "orthonormal" (with a t). Do you know where we can find a precise definition ?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a typo.  It's probably rather more common than other typos, because the letters "t,h,g" are very close to each other on a standard keyboard.  As a result, it actually does appear in the literature rather more often than you'd expect, and always without definition.

(As such, I believe this post qualifies as a legitimate research question and shouldn't be closed, despite the fact that it's about a trivial typographical error.  Hilarious!)

For instance, here it is in a [google books search result](http://books.google.ca/books?id=UjvGL11zJO0C&pg=PA108&lpg=PA108&dq=orghogonal&source=bl&ots=GcMUN-JMeT&sig=BcEbosInyImIQCpCb8a8HIWTIgI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=R9MGT_ehLbDV4QSYx82NCA&ved=0CCYQ6AEwATgK#v=onepage&q=orghogonal&f=false).  It appears in the second page of an article in a collection of proceedings of a conference, without any definition.  Elsewhere in the article it seems to be talking about orthogonality.

Of course I'd be happy to be proven wrong - probably the best thing to do is to contact someone who's used the word in print.  Maybe they know what it means.

Edit: [More evidence](http://domino.watson.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/1e4115aea78b6e7c85256b360066f0d4/0ac0c2bf76d2c5d785257842004ebac0!OpenDocument): compare the title to that of the pdf link, [Also this:](http://books.google.ca/books?id=f4f2wNPv5hYC&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=orghogonal&source=bl&ots=2EqQYV6S45&sig=cW7g_SmC7ZGDQMmtmYL1bvs-100&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NtgGT-bpOdKP4gTAssWNCA&ved=0CE8Q6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=orghogonal&f=false) where the previous sentence uses the word "orthogonal")

Comment: If someone does contact a user of the word, please record the outcome as part of this answer either as an edit or a comment.

Comment: I've been trying... haven't found an email address yet!

Comment: Dear @Benjamin Young: I would suggest avoiding link shorteners (like goo.gl) as they aid link-rot and prevent people from seeing the destination of the link. To get visually short links with a textual description, try the syntax `[link-description](http://link-url)`, which gives the result [link-description](http://link-url). Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't know about that.  Fixed.

Comment: orthogonal vectors are perpendicular, while orghogonal vectors are merely perpandicular --- http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=214624

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: And it appears you compute them using "gramm shmit" instead of Gram-Schmidt :)

Comment: I have found an instance in Math Reviews: MR0209663 (35 #560) Peetre, Jaak, Some remarks on continuous orthogonal expansions, and eigenfunction expansions for positive self-adjoint elliptic operators with variable coefficients, Math. Scand. 17 1965 56–64; "The results depend essentially on an extension to continuous orghogonal expansions of results for discrete orthogonal expansions due to Kaczmarz and Zygmund...."